# Script with commands split & cat

Tags: bash, scripts, cat, merge, split

I want to split an image.jpg into parts and merge it again. 
I used the following commands:

```bsh
split -b 1440 image.jpg # It divides it into 6 parts.
cat xaa.jpg xab.jpg xac.jpg xad.jpg xae.jpg xaf.jpg > new-image.jpg
```

Now I want a script that does the same work of the previous commands.

Comment: Join the two commands together and run them sequentially with `&&`

Comment: How to do that please help me I really need to know how ?

Comment: what do you mean by _a script that does the same work_? please be more specific. do you want to create a command?

Comment: I want to create a script split an image.jpeg into parts and mege it again 
Do you see what I mean?

Comment: `split -b 1440 image.jpg && cat xaa.jpg xab.jpg xac.jpg xad.jpg xae.jpg xaf.jpg > new-image.jpg` That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# test whether first argument exists and is a regular file, if not exit
[ -f "$1" ] || exit 1

# put 1440 bytes per output file
split -b 1440 "$1" "$1". &&

# merge files again
cat "$1".* >"${1%/*}/new-${1##*/}"
```

A script begins with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) specifying the program it should be run with, in this case that’s `/bin/bash`. First we test for the first argument to the script to be a regular file and exit if it’s not. The `split` command splits the file given as the first argument and creates output files like `image.jpg.aa` for a file `image.jpg`. Only if `split` exited successfully, the `cat` command merges them again using [`bash`’s Pathname Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) and [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and saves the output (i.e. the merged file) as `new-image.jpg` for a file `image.jpg`.

Save this script as e.g. `splitmerge.bash`, make it executable with `chmod +x splitmerge.bash` and run it with:

```
splitmerge.bash image.jpg
```

All output files are created in the input file’s directory regardless your current directory. If the script and/or the file to split is not located in your current directory, use absolute paths instead, e.g.:

```
~/scripts/splitmerge.bash /home/thmk/test/image.jpg
```